# Android Honeycomb 3.1 webclient with flash content - not working :-(

Tags: android, webview, android-3.0-honeycomb

I am trying to embed a webclient in my app, and the page has flash content, i'm pretty sure it's loading the flash, but it's not displaying it.  Anyone know the problem?

```
public class FlashTestActivity extends Activity {

final Activity activity = this;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {
            activity.setTitle("Loading...");
            activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

            if(progress == 100)
                activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        }
    });

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
        {
            // Handle the error
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });

    webView.loadUrl("http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 'android:hardwareAccelerated="true"' property to application field of project Manifest.